# Animate NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, animation, transform, scale, nswindow

I would like to animate a custom NSWindow (just containing an image) with a scale transform.
I was using previously an CGSPrivate function but I would like to publish my app to teh appstore, so it no more an option.

Do you know how I can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to scale an `NSWindow` instance, you should look into the `setFrame:display:animate:` function.